# i want to update my database

Tags: php, database, sql-update

1-now already i added some texts on my database then after i want to update my database

anybody can help me?
i hope someone can help me

```
<?php
       mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO tasks (task,status) 
       VALUES ('$task','$status')");
       header('location:SIMPLE.PHP');
       }
         }
             if (isset($_GET['check_selected'])) {
                foreach ($_GET['check_selected'] as $key => $value) {
               $row = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id  =  
            $value;") or die(mysqli_error($db));
          }
               }
                $tasks = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY id DESC");
             ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
   <body>

            <form method="GET" action="SIMPLE.PHP">
             <input type="text" name="search" class="status_input" placeholder="TEXT" /> 

                    <input id='textbox' type='checkbox' value='1' name='status'>

                    <button type="submit" class="add_btn" name="submit">Add</button>                                         
                      <p><?php echo $errors; ?></p>
                     </form>                
              <form action="SIMPLE.PHP" method="GET">

               <tbody>
                   <tr>  
             <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="save">DELETE</button></p>
       <?php
           foreach ($rows as $row_id  => $row)
       {
       ?>  
                    <input name="check_selected[]" type="checkbox"  value=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"/>
          <input name = "checkbox[]" type="checkbox"  id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo     $row['status'];?>" 

                 <?PHP if($row['status']){echo 'checked';
                 }   
                 ?>
              >
              <td class= "task"><?php echo $row['task']?></td>
          <?PHP
           }
          ?>
          </tr>      
          </tbody>
         </form>
        </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where exactly are you stuck? Your code only inserts and deletes.

Comment: If you can insert and delete, and if updating is the problem, write an [update](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) statement by following the same php semantics you have for insert and delete.

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks with that code. Have a read of the use of prepared statements.